# Is jquery.cookies hosted on the Google CDN?

Tags: jquery, google-cdn

I can't seem to find the jquery plugin for **cookies** on googles CDN.  Is it only available for download?

Comment: Its available on other CDNs. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57406593/369005

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not on the Google CDN. All the libraries on the CDN are listed here - http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/

Comment: So I'll need to host it locally on my server?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this will do? http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jquery.cookie
It also supports SSL

Answer (score 8):

It is not available on Google's CDN.

But cdnjs makes it available here: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-cookie/

cdnjs supports http/https/spdy. Seems to be more popular than jsDelivr: http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jquery.cookie

Uptime is good http://stats.pingdom.com/4jg86a2wqei0/687131/history

Answer (score 3):

According to **CDNperf** (http://www.cdnperf.com), at the time of writing this answer, the best CDN hosting for **jquery.cookies** is **jsDelivr** (http://jsdelivr.com), both in terms of latency (<100ms) and minimum downtime.

Remember to link the .JS file from your HTML **without the protocol** prefix, so that it works both with HTTP and HTTPs:

```
//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it via http://cachedcommons.org, but SSL isn't available if that's a blocker.

Comment: No longer available. Seems like the CDN is gone.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not available on Google's Public CDN. But it is available on many other Public and Opensource CDNs. Here is the link from [jQuery Cookie CDN](https://pagecdn.com/lib/jquery-cookie) for you:

```
<script src="https://pagecdn.io/lib/jquery-cookie/v1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js" integrity="sha256-uEFhyfv3UgzRTnAZ+SEgvYepKKB0FW6RqZLrqfyUNug=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

have you ever tried: http://cdnjs.com/

Its available there.